# The weapons of Dovid Hamelech in the Beis HaMikdosh

Tags: beis-hamikdash, king-david, melachim-kings-book-of

In [2 Melachim, 11:10](https://www.sefaria.org/II_Kings.11.10?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), the Torah says:

> And to the captains over hundreds did the priest give king David’s spear and shields, that were in the temple of the L-rd.

- Why did the Beis HaMikdosh have a chamber, or chambers with weapons in it?
- Where was this chamber, or chambers located in the Beis HaMikdosh, and how big was this chamber?

Are there any descriptions on this?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but Malbim took me on a little tour - the shields were made by Shlomo (Kings I:10:16), made from "King David's gold", originally placed in Shlomo's palace, and were later stolen by King Sishak (Kings I:14:26). If you follow sources from here, you might find your answer. This is controversial among the commentaries...

Comment: I always assumed that the chambers (ta'im) built around the sides of the Temple were the storehouses.

Comment: could the weapons be held in those storehouses?

Comment: A contribution to the answer. Both [Radak and Ralbag](https://www.sefaria.org/II_Kings.11.10?lang=bi&with=Radak&lang2=en) say that these weapons were sanctified to the Temple by Dovid and that's why they were kept there. Similarly [2 Samuel 8 (7)](https://www.sefaria.org/II_Samuel.8.7?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en), regarding the gold shields carried by Hadadezer, Rashi says “from all these wars [Dovid] gathered consecrated items for the needs of the Beis Hamikdash."

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok the spears Radak talks about. For what where they used in the Beis HaMikdosh? I would understand that if Dovid gathered items from "all these wars", as Rashi points out. But what would be the need for spears and other weapons in a Beis HaMikdosh?